# How to mock the 'Request.Cookies.AllKeys' in unit test c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, mocking, session-cookies

I need to get values in the below mentioned cookie in unit test.

```
string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
```

The values should be `ASP.NET_SessionId`, `__RequestVerificationToken`.

Is it possible to create a mock for the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can either create a fake HttpContext that encapsulates the desired information

```
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly MockRequest request;
    public MockHttpContext(HttpCookieCollection cookies) {
        this.request = new MockRequest(cookies);
    }

    public override HttpRequestBase Request {
        get {
            return request;
        }
    }

    public class MockRequest : HttpRequestBase {
        private readonly HttpCookieCollection cookies;
        public MockRequest(HttpCookieCollection cookies) {
            this.cookies = cookies;
        }

        public override HttpCookieCollection Cookies {
            get {
                return cookies;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and used like this

```
//Arrange
var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId"));
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken"));

var context = new MockHttpContext(cookies);
var Request = context.Request;//This is just for demonstrative purposes

string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
```

Or you can do that same with a mocking framework.

This example uses Moq

```
var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId"));
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken"));

var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockHttpContext.Setup(m => m.Request.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
```

This example uses NSubstitute

```
var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId"));
cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken"));

var mockHttpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();
mockHttpContext.Request.Cookies.Returns(cookies);
```